# onmouseover= not working with chrome?

Tags: html, css, onmouseover

My question is, **onmouseover=** internet Explorer is working but

whit google chrome is not working.

What I have to do?

Thank you and regards..

```
<a href="photo_view.php?photo_sid={row.col.PHOTO_SID}"><img id="{row.col.PHOTO_SID}" width="250" height="200" src="{row.col.PHOTO_THUMB}" alt="{row.col.PHOTO_TITLE}" border="0"  onmouseover="trailOn('{row.col.PHOTO_PREVIEW}','{row.col.PHOTO_TITLE}','{row.col.USERNAME}','{row.col.SITENAME}','Size: {row.col.PHOTO_WIDTH}x{row.col.PHOTO_HEIGHT} dpi &#40;{row.col.RESOLUTION}&#41;<br>','{row.col.PHOTO_PRICE}','{row.col.FULLNAME}','{row.col.PHOTO_PWIDTH}','{row.col.PHOTO_PHEIGHT}');" onmouseout="trailOff();"></a>
```

Comment: If i copy your code it works in chrome, you should check for errors in the browser inspector(F12) when you mouse over the <a>.

Comment: Thank you for unswer but there is a no errors. Cust it's not work whit chrome.

Comment: If you want you can check the link, (http://www.chromestock.com/search.php)

Comment: I fix my problem. in popus.js file there is write some where  **opera**, and I chance all **opera** whit  **chrome** and OK.